# Uncaught TypeError: seatsIndex is not a function

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

Thanks in advance for your help with this issue. I'm re-factoring a practice project using a MVC pattern with OOP, and I'm getting an error that states:

```
mvc.js:57 Uncaught TypeError: seatsIndex is not a function
    at View.updateSelectedSeats (mvc.js:57)
    at new View (mvc.js:27)
    at mvc.js:103
```

What I'm attempting to do is update local storage on the browser to separate this function from the View portion of the code.

The View has a method called updateSelectedSeats() that calls seatIndex with the data captured in the index variable. The error originates here (not a function). I've tried debugging and console logs in various places, from what I can tell - it seems to be that it's simply not a function at the time of being called.

Here is how I've put together the code:

```
class Model {

setMovieData(movieIndex, moviePrice) {
    localStorage.setItem('selectedMovieIndex', movieIndex);
    localStorage.setItem('selectedMoviePrice', moviePrice);
  }

  selectedSeats(index) {
    localStorage.setItem('selectedSeats', JSON.stringify(index));
  }
}

class View {
  screenContainer = document.querySelector('.screen__container');
  unoccupiedSeats = document.querySelectorAll(
    '.seat__row .seat__position:not(.seat__occupied)'
  );
  count = document.querySelector('#checkout__text--count');
  total = document.querySelector('#checkout__text--total');

  constructor() {
    this.movieSelect = document.querySelector('#movie');
    this.ticketPrice = +this.movieSelect.value;
    this.populateUI();
    this._seatHandler();
    this.updateSelectedSeats();
  }

  _seatHandler() {
    this.screenContainer.addEventListener('click', e => {
      const seat = e.target.classList.contains('seat__position');
      const occupied = e.target.classList.contains('seat__occupied');

      if (seat && !occupied) e.target.classList.toggle('seat__selected');
      this.updateSelectedSeats();
    });
  }

  bindSetMovieData(handler) {
    this.movieSelect.addEventListener('change', e => {
      this.ticketPrice = +e.target.value;
      handler(e.target.selectedIndex, e.target.value);
      this.updateSelectedSeats();
    });
  }

  updateSelectedSeats(seatsIndex) {
    const selectedSeats = document.querySelectorAll(
      '.seat__row .seat__selected'
    );

    const index = [...selectedSeats].map(seat =>
      [...this.unoccupiedSeats].indexOf(seat)
    );
    // debugger;
    seatsIndex(index);

    // localStorage.setItem('selectedSeats', JSON.stringify(index));

    const numSeats = selectedSeats.length;
    this.count.innerText = numSeats;
    this.total.innerText = numSeats * this.ticketPrice;
  }

  populateUI() {
    const selectedSeats = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selectedSeats'));

    if (selectedSeats !== null && selectedSeats.length > 1)
      this.unoccupiedSeats.forEach((seat, index) => {
        if (selectedSeats.indexOf(index) > -1)
          seat.classList.add('seat__selected');
      });

    const selectedMovieIndex = localStorage.getItem('selectedMovieIndex');

    if (selectedMovieIndex !== null) {
      this.movieSelect.selectedIndex = selectedMovieIndex;
    }

    this.ticketPrice = localStorage.getItem('selectedMoviePrice');
  }
}

class Controller {
  constructor(model, view) {
    this.model = model;
    this.view = view;

    this.view.bindSetMovieData(this.handleSetMovieData);
    this.view.updateSelectedSeats(this.handleSelectedSeats);
  }

  handleSetMovieData = (index, value) => {
    this.model.setMovieData(index, value);
  };

  handleSelectedSeats = index => {
    this.model.selectedSeats(index);
  };
}

const app = new Controller(new Model(), new View());
```

Any thoughts on how I could get this solved or what I've done incorrectly?

Comment: You're calling `updateSelectedSeats` with no arguments

Comment: Thanks @RobertoZvjerković - If I only need the arguments for the controller to pass onto the model, what would be the best way to call this method in the constructor (and other methods that use it like _seatHandler, etc)?

Comment: I've just tried adding `updateSelectedSeats(seatsIndex = [])` to auto-set the argument, but it doesn't seem that that's the issue. The function works with or without it, but gets stuck at the point of calling `seatIndex()` within that method.

Comment: `seatsIndex = []` doesn't work because you're setting it to an array. `seatsIndex = () => {}` might work, but I think the logic itself is the problem here. What do you want to do with the function that can or might not take an argument? You surely don't want the call the function from the argument if it was not passed.

Comment: Ok, I see. So the goal of the `updateSelectedSeats()` method is to do some UI changes as well as upload an array `localStorage.setItem('selectedSeats', JSON.stringify(index))`. The struggle I'm having is to turn the localStorage line into a separate function that the controller has access to, avoiding having the view class talking to the model directly. I'm completely stuck on how to do this. I understand how to have the controller deal with event listeners (having a handler argument), but not sure how the controller should talk to local storage from an event that takes place in the view.

Answer (score 0):

As per the **updateSelectedSeats** function Declaration, you are having parameter **seatsIndex**, which would expect some arguments to be passed whenever you invoked or call the function **updateSelectedSeats**.

- As per your case you are only trying to pass arguments through **Controller** class and in other places you are trying to call function "updateSelectedSeats" without any arguments passing. So the **updateSelectedSeats** function which you are trying to invoked without arguments from different locations will result the  **seatsIndex** value **undefined**. So you can add a validation check like this to prevent error.

  ```
   updateSelectedSeats(seatsIndex) {
   const selectedSeats = document.querySelectorAll(
     '.seat__row .seat__selected'
   );

   const index = [...selectedSeats].map(seat =>
     [...this.unoccupiedSeats].indexOf(seat)
   );
   // debugger;
  ```

  **if(typeof seatsIndex === 'function') //// or you can check if(seatsIndex) truthy value.
  seatsIndex(index);**

  ```
   // localStorage.setItem('selectedSeats', JSON.stringify(index));

   const numSeats = selectedSeats.length;
   this.count.innerText = numSeats;
   this.total.innerText = numSeats * this.ticketPrice;
  ```

  }

Comment: Thanks for this! It helped as far as realising what the problem is, but I think there is something wrong with my actual logic. Check out the comment I left on the original post above, any insights would be amazing.